# MySql - Avoid duplicate records on update

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have the following update query which runs when a user logs in to their account having place items in their cart prior to logging in (a temporary account set up on the table)...

```
UPDATE cart_items SET account_id=$account WHERE account_id=$cookieId;
```

This occasionally creates duplicate results looking something like this:

```
id | account_id | itemNumber | itemQuantity
------------------------------------------
20 | 10         | 6          | 2
25 | 10         | 6          | 1
```

What I would like to do i write a query which avoids creating these duplicate records and just leaves a single record like this:

```
id | account_id | itemNumber | itemQuantity
------------------------------------------
20 | 10         | 6          | 3
```

I think using `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` might be what I'm looking for but I can't get my head around it. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

|| Updated ||

Let's assume that you have a non-logged in user with the temporary id 15 and that he has ordered 2 items with itemNumber 6:

```
id | account_id | itemNumber | itemQuantity
------------------------------------------
20 | 15         | 6          | 2
```

The temporary id is stored in the variable $cookieId, which has value 15.
Now let's assume that this user logs into his account with id stored in $account, with the value 10.

As a part of the log-in process you want to perform your query:

```
UPDATE cart_items SET account_id=$account WHERE account_id=$cookieId;
```

(Even though prepared statements should be something you would want to take a look at).

The entry should now look like this:

```
id | account_id | itemNumber | itemQuantity
------------------------------------------
20 | 10         | 6          | 2
```

Now let's assume that user 10 wants to buy 1 more item 6, then it would make most sense to

```
SELECT * FROM cart_items WHERE account_id = $account AND itemNumber = $itemNumber; // $itemNumber is 6
```

If the query returns true, then you

```
UPDATE cart_items SET itemQuantity = itemQuantity+$numerOfItemsInOrder WHERE $account = $account AND itemNumber = $itemNumber; // $itemNumber is 6
```

, you insert otherwise.

You definitely don't want to update the account_id if the user logs out, only when he logs in.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the feedback... Here's the logic behind my query. A user (not logged in) adds items to their cart and as such an entry is made into a user accounts table and the cart_items table. This ID is stored as a cookie on their machine. However, if this user has an account and then logs in, I want to merge the cart items of the registered account and temporary cookie based account, then remove the temporary account from the database. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense. I'll try to provide a better suggestion. I'm at work so I'll see what my coffee break allows me to do.

Comment: Ha! thanks. It's not hugely urgent (yet) so don't stress too much.

Comment: Tell me, does the second entry (25 | 10 | 6 | 1) happens automatically (which, of course, doesn't make sense) or does that current user just happened to have ordered 1 more of the item 6? I'm just thinking if it should be a part of the log-in process to fetch all items from the cart known to be ordered by the temp user and update his id before he can do any more orders. Basically: Do you do the update when he orders again or when he logs in?

Comment: Well, they have placed 1 of item number 6 in cart when not logged in, and previously placed 2 of the same when logged in. So I'm making the assumption they want 3 in total (I'll show a message to warn them of this after they log in). The update is made when he logs in...

Comment: I made an update, feel free to give me more information if you think I'm still miss-understanding you. The magic is probably just to check if an entry exists and either update or insert depending on the situation. This problem just seems to be too simple to be causing a problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32082/discussion-between-tom-and-jonast92)

Comment: I've managed to achieve the desired results without the need to put any more php checks in the page. If you can think of a way to make this method more elegant I'd be interested in seeing, because it really doesn't look like a pretty solution to me! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's what I've done... It might be a bit long winded but it works...

```
UPDATE cart_items SET account_id=$account WHERE account_id=$cookieId;

UPDATE cart_items t
  JOIN (
    SELECT MinID, b.itemQuantity LatestName
    FROM cart_items b
    JOIN (
      SELECT MIN(id) MinID, MAX(id) MaxID
      FROM cart_items
      GROUP BY account_id, itemNumber
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) g ON b.id = g.MaxID
  ) rs ON t.id = rs.MinID
SET t.itemQuantity = t.itemQuantity+LatestName;

DELETE `cart_items` 
FROM `cart_items`
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(`id`) as `id`, `account_id`, `itemNumber`
   FROM `cart_items` 
   GROUP BY `account_id`, `itemNumber`
) as `KeepRows` ON
   `cart_items`.`id` = `KeepRows`.`id`
WHERE
   `KeepRows`.`id` IS NULL
```